# GHC API equivalent of adding a C/C++ file/object to the compilation

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-api

Say I have this GHC command:

```
ghc -ibuild/foreign/somelib \
  -lstdc++ \
  -outputdir "$buildDir" \
  foreign/somelib/somelib.o \
  src/Main.hs -o "$buildDir/Main"
```

The somewhat equivalent `runGhc` command is this, I think:

```hs
runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
  (setOutputFile (Just "build/Main") -> dflags) <- getSessionDynFlags

  setSessionDynFlags $ dflags
    { importPaths      = [".", "build/foreign/somelib"]
    , ldInputs         = [Option "-lstdc++"]
    , libraryPaths     = ["build/foreign/somelib"]
    , objectDir        = Just "build"
    , hiDir            = Just "build"
    }

  target <- guessTarget "src/Main.hs" Nothing Nothing

  setTargets [target]
  load LoadAllTargets
  return ()
```

However, that doesn't include the object file, and from looking at the documentation I am not sure how one would add it. Putting it as a target doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think you need to set them in the options of the linker info (but don't quote me on this).

Comment: Ahh, that was the solution, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77583854/ghc-api-equivalent-of-adding-a-c-c-file-object-to-the-compilation?noredirect=1#comment136778195_77583854), the solution is to pass it via the `ldInputs`:

```hs
  setSessionDynFlags $ dflags
    { importPaths      = [".", "build/foreign/somelib"]
    , ldInputs         = [Option "foreign/somelib/somelib.o", Option "-lstdc++"]
    , libraryPaths     = ["build/foreign/somelib"]
    , objectDir        = Just "build"
    , hiDir            = Just "build"
    }
```

Just like when working with `ld`, the order in which the `ldInputs` are defined matter.